# Display 3D view with Cordova (PhoneGap)

Tags: objective-c, cordova, plugins

I am creating an iOS application with Cordova and Jquery Mobile. In a specific page, I want to display a 3D view of a car, a house, whatever. The 3D representation is an Objective C plugin that I linked to my Cordova project.

On my HMI, I have several tool panels that I can expend/collapse. These panels contain several tools that I must be able to use on my 3D view. I have created those panels with Jquery mobile :

```
<div class="panelRight">
    <div class="panelRightContent">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false"> <a href="#" data-role="button">Tool 1</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Tool 2</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Tool 3</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Tool 4</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Tool 5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is : when I use my application I can't set the plugin position in the middle of my layers. More precisely, either I send the plugin view to the front and I can't expend/collapse my labels anymore, or I send it to the back and the plugin is hidden by the Cordova background activity.

Is there a way to hide or delete the default Cordova background so I could display my plugin in a specific area under my HMI (the panels should then expend ON the plugin view). Do you think there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I will advice not using any objective C plugin with Cordova as it will not be possible to use this plugin inside your HTML application.

Would it be possible to use some css3 or js to display your 3D model ?
http://tridiv.com/ 
http://threejs.org/

Three js is a powerful tool.
Hope this help

Comment: Those solutions are quite impressive, but unfortunately it is necessary for me tu use an Objective C plugin since it is the way the project has been thought and I have not developed it, I am just using it. More basically, my problem is the same either I use a 3D plugin or just a basic plugin that displays a colored background i.e  with the function initWithFrame:CGRectMake

Comment: The html <a> will not be able to interact with the objective C plugin. For all i know it's either objective C or cordova and a plugin capable to communicate between those 2 does not exist at the moment